# Problem creating dynamic date parameter in Google Data Studio

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio, query-string

I am trying to add date parameters for my start and end date in my code. The code seeks to amortize revenue over a period of time selected from the date parameter.

However, I get the error, 'Table-value function not found'. Anyone has an idea why I'm getting this error?

Edit:

All data are from tables in my BigQuery. I happened to append multiple tables and saved as a View, from which I am querying them.

The original table has columns like:

```
User | fullname | subscription_start_date | subscription_end_date | Amount
```

I wrote a code that amortized the Amount by considering the subscription duration and the period selected from the dynamic date input.

The issue now is that, after writing the code below, I got the error of Table-function not being available. Not sure what that means.

```
CASE
--Sub falls within the selected period
WHEN DATE_DIFF(@DS_END_DATE,'2000-01-01', DAY) >= DATE_DIFF(end_at,'2000-01-01', DAY) AND DATE_DIFF(@DS_START_DATE,'2000-01-01', DAY) <= DATE_DIFF(start_at,'2000-01-01', DAY) THEN CAST(t1.amount AS NUMERIC)
--Selected period falls within the sub period
WHEN DATE_DIFF(@DS_END_DATE,'2000-01-01', DAY) <= DATE_DIFF(end_at,'2000-01-01', DAY) AND DATE_DIFF(@DS_START_DATE,'2000-01-01', DAY) >= DATE_DIFF(start_at,'2000-01-01', DAY) THEN 
(DATE_DIFF(@DS_END_DATE,'2000-01-01', DAY) - DATE_DIFF(@DS_START_DATE,'2000-01-01', DAY))/(DATE_DIFF(end_at,'2000-01-01', DAY) - DATE_DIFF(start_at,'2000-01-01', DAY)) * CAST(t1.amount AS NUMERIC)
-- Subscription starts within but ends outside the selected period
WHEN DATE_DIFF(@DS_END_DATE, '2000-01-01', DAY) <= DATE_DIFF(end_at,'2000-01-01', DAY) AND DATE_DIFF(@DS_START_DATE,'2000-01-01', DAY) <= DATE_DIFF(start_at,'2000-01-01', DAY) THEN 
(DATE_DIFF(@DS_END_DATE, '2000-01-01', DAY) - DATE_DIFF(start_at, '2000-01-01', DAY))/(DATE_DIFF(end_at, '2000-01-01', DAY) - DATE_DIFF(start_at, '2000-01-01', DAY)) * CAST(t1.amount AS NUMERIC)
-- Subscription starts outside of but ends within the selected period
WHEN DATE_DIFF(@DS_END_DATE, '2000-01-01', DAY) >= DATE_DIFF(end_at, '2000-01-01', DAY) AND DATE_DIFF(@DS_START_DATE, '2000-01-01', DAY) >= DATE_DIFF(start_at, '2000-01-01', DAY) THEN 
(DATE_DIFF(end_at, '2000-01-01', DAY) - DATE_DIFF(@DS_START_DATE, '2000-01-01', DAY))/(DATE_DIFF(end_at, '2000-01-01', DAY) - DATE_DIFF(start_at, '2000-01-01', DAY)) * CAST(t1.amount AS NUMERIC)
END AS real_revenue
```

The real_revenue is supposed to be the contribution per subscription for the time period selected.

NB: Data Studio date parameters are represented by @DS_START_DATE and @DS_END_DATE

Answer (score 0):

Have a quick look at this [Doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views) it seems to imply you cannot use query parameters in views and @DS_START_DATE, @DS_END_DATE are query parameters.

If you include your original query (the one used to build the view) as a sub query you this should work fine. You can then add custom queries into datastudio when you add a datasource, just copy the query into that UI, and it should work with the Date parameters (if ticked)

Side note: I've simplified your query a little and add the sub query.

```
SELECT *,
CASE
--Sub falls within the selected period
WHEN DATE_DIFF(@DS_END_DATE, end_at, DAY) > 0 AND DATE_DIFF(@DS_START_DATE, start_at, DAY) < 0 THEN CAST(t1.amount as NUMERIC) 

--Selected period falls within the sub period
WHEN DATE_DIFF(@DS_END_DATE, end_at, DAY) < 0 AND DATE_DIFF(@DS_START_DATE, start_at, DAY) > 0 THEN  
DATE_DIFF(@DS_END_DATE, @DS_START_DATE, DAY) / DATE_DIFF(end_at, start_at, DAY) * CAST(t1.amount AS NUMERIC)

-- Subscription starts within but ends outside the selected period
WHEN DATE_DIFF(@DS_END_DATE, end_at, DAY) > 0 AND DATE_DIFF(@DS_START_DATE, start_at, DAY) > 0 THEN 
DATE_DIFF(@DS_END_DATE, start_at, DAY) / DATE_DIFF(end_at, start_at, DAY) * CAST(t1.amount AS NUMERIC)

-- Subscription starts outside of but ends within the selected period
WHEN DATE_DIFF(@DS_END_DATE, end_at, DAY) < 0 AND DATE_DIFF(@DS_START_DATE, start_at, DAY) > 0 THEN 
DATE_DIFF(end_at,@DS_START_DATE, DAY) / DATE_DIFF(end_at, start_at, DAY) * CAST(t1.amount AS NUMERIC)

END AS real_revenue

FROM ( 
  -- YOUR ORIGINAL VIEW CREATION QUERY
)
WHERE
 -- any conditions you might want to add.
```